# print out a message that says miss if guess of a character is wrong. game of hangman

Tags: java, class, methods, character

```
   do {            
            System.out.println("Word: " + secretWord.getWordMask());
            //System.out.print("Guesses: " + guesses);
            System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            String guess = keyboard.next();              
            WordHider revealChar = new WordHider();                
            revealChar.revealLetter(guess);
            System.out.println(revealChar.getWordMask());
            secretWord.revealLetter(guess);
            if (guess != ???)  {
                System.out.println("Miss");
            }
```

so ive got that much and what it does it ask the user to guess a letter, but what i cant figure out is how to make it so if the letter they guess isnt right, to print a "miss" message.

```
public int revealLetter(String letter) {
    int count = 0;
    String newFoundWord = "";
    if (letter.length() == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
            if ((secretWord.charAt(i) == letter.charAt(0))
                    && (wordMask.charAt(i) == HIDE_CHAR.charAt(0))) {
                count++;
                newFoundWord += letter;
            }
            else {
                newFoundWord += wordMask.charAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
    wordMask = newFoundWord;
    return count;
```

the above code is the code that reveals the letter if its guessed.

Comment: What is this `getWordMask` method that you call on `secretWord`? Is `secretWord` an instance of some user-created class?

Comment: `getWordMask` returns the `wordMask` which is the `secretWord` in all *'s

Comment: Here's a recommendation: instead of passing a `String` as a parameter to `revealLetter`, use a `char` instead. It will save you all the `charAt(0)`'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your `secretWord.revealLetter(guess)` which returns the `count` of how many times `guess` is in `secretWord`, which is 0 when it's a miss. So you can put that in the `if` condition:

```
if (secretWord.revealLetter(guess) == 0)  {
    System.out.println("Miss");
}
```

You can remove the call to `secretWord.revealLetter(guess)` before the `if`, since you only need to call it once.